# Searching element in multidimensional array - using recursion

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to write own searching function in multilevel array using recursion.

```
$arr=[923,[123,158,12,[999,998]],111,12];
        function search($arr,$searched){
            static $position;
            static $level=0;
            foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
                if(is_array($v)){
                    $level++;
                    search($v,$searched);
                }
                elseif($v==$searched){
                    $position[]=['level'=>$level,'key'=>$k];
                }
            }
            return dd($position);
        }
```

Results are incorrect for last 2 elements 111, 12. I get NULL. For the rest it's ok. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function search($arr,$searched){
    static $position;
    static $level=0;
    $nextLevelArray = [];
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){ //first check only integers
        if(is_array($v)){
            $nextLevelArray[] = $v; //save array elements
        } elseif($v==$searched){ //found and save
            $position[]=['level'=>$level,'key'=>$k];
        }
    }
    if(!empty($nextLevelArray)){
        foreach($nextLevelArray as $nextLevelElement){ //check array elements and again and again...
            $level++;
            search($nextLevelElement,$searched);
        }
    }
    return dd($position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if could be helpful, but if you want to try a different approach you can write the function like this:

```
    $arr=[923,[123,158,12,[999,998]],111,12];

    function array_search_recursive($arr, $searched, $index = []) {
        if (is_array($arr)) {
            $solutions = [];
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $new_index = $index;
                array_push($new_index, $key);
                $paths = array_search_recursive($value, $searched, $new_index);
                $solutions = array_merge($solutions, $paths);
            }
            return $solutions;
        } else {
            if (is_array($searched) && in_array($arr, $searched)) {
                return [$index];
            } else if (!is_array($searched) && $arr === $searched) {
                return [$index];
            } else {
                return [];
            }
        }
    }

    $res = array_search_recursive($arr, [12, 999]);
    print_r($res);
```

After the execution:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)
```

with that function you can search multiple values and obtain a list of path to get that values. So, for example, this array:

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 0
        )
```

specifies that you can get one of your desired values inside the array at:

- the index 1 ([123,158,12,[999,998]])
- then at index 3 ([999,998])
- then at index 0 (999).

You can convert the output format of mine to yours easily.